# Get package of Python object

Tags: python, introspection

Given an object or type I can get the object's module using the `inspect` package

#### Example

Here, given a function I get the module that contains that function:

```
>>> inspect.getmodule(np.memmap)
<module 'numpy.core.memmap' from ...>
```

However what I really want is to get the top-level module that corresponds to the package, in this case `numpy` rather than `numpy.core.memmap`.

```
>>> function_that_I_want(np.memmap)
<module 'numpy' from ...>
```

*Given an object or a module, how do I get the top-level module?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have imported the submodule, then the top-level module must also be loaded in `sys.modules` already (because that's how the import system works).  So, something dumb and simple like this should be reliable:

```
import sys, inspect

def function_that_I_want(obj):
    mod = inspect.getmodule(obj)
    base, _sep, _stem = mod.__name__.partition('.')
    return sys.modules[base]
```

The module's [`__package__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package__) attribute may be interesting for you also (or future readers).  For submodules, this is a string set to the parent package's name (which is not necessarily the top-level module name).  See [PEP366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) for more details.