# How can I dynamically find out a subclass' package name in Python?

Tags: python, django

For context, I'm writing a library that uses Django's ORM. I don't want users of my library to have to define the `app_label` every time they subclass my custom `Model` superclass, instead I want to enforce a standard structure for projects created with it that makes sure the package name of every class that subclasses my `Model` superclass will equal the `app_label`. Here's the code I currently have:

```
class Model(django.db.models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        # package_name = ???
        cls._meta.app_label = package_name
```

The `???` part is what I can't seem to figure out. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `package_name`, can you give an example?

Comment: @IainShelvington I mean the name of the package the module where the subclass was defined is in.

Answer (score -1):

I found [an answer to my question on a slightly different question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43462865/13411797). This is how I implemented it:

```
class Model(django.db.models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        mod = inspect.getmodule(cls)
        base, _sep, _stem = mod.__name__.partition('.')
        cls._meta.app_label = base
```

Alternatively, this should also work:

```
class Model(django.db.models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        mod = inspect.getmodule(cls)
        cls._meta.app_label = mod.__package__.split('.')[-1]
```